# Euler-Lagrange equations for this system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I haven't done this calculations in a long time.

Suppose you have a point of mass $m$ constrained to moved to a trajectory described by $y = x^2$ (you have gravity going on the opposite of the $y$ axis.

I'm asked to find the motion equations for the particle, I know I need to use the Euler Lagrange equations for this.

With this in mind the Lagrangian of my system is

$$
L = T - U
$$

where $T$ and $U$ are respectively

$$
T = \frac{1}{2} m (v_x^2 + v_y^2) \;\;, \;\; U = mgy
$$

However the system is constrained and has 1 degree of freedom and this is where I started to get confused as far as I remember I need to parametrize the curve, using arc length. This lead me to the parametrization

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x = s \\
y = s^2
\end{array}
\right.
$$

The length of the curve is given by

$$
l(s) = \int_{0}^s \sqrt{1 + s'^2} ds'
$$

And my intention at the beginning was to solve the integral and then attempt to invert it, so I can reparametrize the curve using arc length. However despite I can compute the integral I cannot invert the equation so the reparametrization is not feasable to me.

So I looked up some notes I have and essentially the lagrangian was simply written as

$$
L = -mgx^2 - \frac{1}{2} m v_x^2
$$

Which I think it's wrong since the mass moves also vertically not just horizontally so the kinetic energy due to movement on the $y$ axis is missing.

Is it possible to solve this problem? I have the feeling is one of those classic physics problems but I can't quite figure.

Comment: In this case I think you can directly use the constraint. The velocity in x and y are related by the tangent vector to the parabola at each point. This means that you can write the Lagrangean as a function of either x (v_x) or y (v_y), reducing this to a one-dimensional problem.

Comment: I can sort of agree for the constraint, what I don't understand is why the solution I looked up doesn't have a $v_y$ component for the velocity. Because clearly the motion is on both axis but it's just constrained. And usually the velocity in these problems is expressed in terms of the rate of change of arc length (as far as I know).

Comment: The constraint implies that $v_y = 2 x v_x$.

Comment: Ok but still we need to add the constraint in the Lagrangian, right? we can't just drop it.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263850/lagrangian-and-hamiltonian-problem-involving-mass-constrained-to-frictonless-par

Comment: Why the downvote? what's wrong with the question?

Comment: @user8469759, I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming there is no algebra error:)

With $y=x^2$, $\dot{y}=2x\dot{x}$, write
\begin{align}
T= \frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2\right)=
\frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{x}^2+4 x^2 \dot{x}^2\right)=
\frac{m}{2}(1+4x^2)\dot{x}^2
\end{align}
so the equation of motions become
\begin{align}
m(1+4x^2)\ddot{x} + 4mx \dot{x}^2 +2mg x=0\, . \tag{1}
\end{align}
To get the harmonic oscillator one first finds the fixed points by going to the Hamiltonian with $p=m(1+4x^2)\dot{x}$:
\begin{align}
H=p^2\left(1-\frac{1}{2m(1+4x^2)}\right)+mgx^2\, ,
\end{align}
to find that $p=0$ and $x=0$ is a fixed point.  The condition $p=0$ implies that $\dot{x}=0$ so you may linearize the equation of motion by setting
\begin{align}
\dot{x}=\epsilon \delta{\dot{x}}\, ,\qquad 
x=\epsilon \delta{x}\, ,\qquad 
\ddot{x}=\epsilon \delta{\ddot{x}}
\end{align}
and expanding (1) to first order in $\epsilon$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\epsilon m \left(\ddot{x}+ 2 g x\right)=0  \tag{2}
\end{align}
with the usual harmonic oscillator solution.

Note that your substitution $y=x^2$ is actually dimensionally awkward in the sense that $y$ has one power of length while $x^2$ has two powers.  As a result the solution you get from (2) will not yield a ``frequency'' with dimensions of inverse time.  You can remedy the situation by using instead $y=\lambda x^2$ where $\lambda$ is some parameter with dimension of inverse length.  This will modify (1) and (2) but will yield a frequency with the right dimensions.

Comment: (+1) for "$y = \lambda x^2$ where $\lambda$ is some parameter with dimension of inverse length"; that's important to consider (although you should use a constant other than $\lambda$, perhaps $a$ instead). Note that you can derive the harmonic oscillator solution by taking $(1)$ and dropping the second and third order terms to get $m \ddot x + 2 m g x = 0$, which is the same as $(2)$.

Comment: @najkim right but the solution is then an oscillation with frequency $\omega=\sqrt{2g}$ which does not have units of inverse time: there's a unit of inverse length missing to get $\omega$ in sec$^{-1}$

Comment: Why do you introduce the prefactor $\epsilon$ to your perturbation from the fixed point?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Not quite. You're making the same mistake that you pointed out in the last paragraph. Remember that $U = mg y =  m g \lambda x^2$ for $\lambda$ with units $\mathrm{m}^{-1}$. Resultingly, your EOM should be $m(1 + 4\lambda x^2)\ddot x + 4m \lambda x \dot x ^2 + 2m g \lambda x$ and the SHO equation becomes $m \ddot x + 2 m g \lambda x = 0$ in the $x \rightarrow 0 $ limit, which is indeed dimensionally correct.

Comment: @najkim I’m not sure I understand.  I know that (1) and (2)  are not dimensionally correct, but that’s the way the OP wrote their question.

Comment: @AlmostClueless it’s a simple way of keeping track of the size of the combination of various terms.

Comment: Not sure why you had to go through the Hamiltonian, but long story short you get an harmonic oscillator by linearizing, is that right? So generally speaking the problem is not an harmonic oscillator but for small perturbation it is. Correct?

Comment: @user8469759 You need to find the fixed point of the motion so you know about which point you want to linearize.  The fixed pots of the motion are given by $\partial_H=\partial_x H=0$ although there are other ways of finding them if you can recast the system in terms of coupled 1st order DEs.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I think you want a fixed point in any description of the dynamical system to find where you want to linearize. I assume your choice (as you probably said already) wasn't the unique one. Another one would've been writing the system of state equation and use those for the fixed point.

Comment: @user8469759 it turns out there’s only one fixed point for this system (at least in the standard way to set it up) but you’re right it only makes sense to linearize near a fixed point.